# How to show css notifications only once (best method)

Tags: php, notifications

Today I was on Facebook and noticed how they show you a notification when you enter a page that has a new feature, but right after you click close the notification disappear forever. If you do nothing, the notification will always be there, if you click close then you can clear your cache, change computres, logout and login again, and the notification will not be there.

My question is, what is the best way to store that info? How can I store that the user has already seen that notification so I don't have to show it again?

Cookies?
Sessions?
Databases?
Javascript?

How?

Comment: Obviously it is database driven since clearing your cache, changing computers do not show the notification again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Save the notification in some notification queue (database)
2. Check whether the notification should be shown (PHP, user visits a site that's appropriate for the notification).
3. If the notification is appropriate for the current context, show the notification (PHP + CSS).
4. If the user dismisses the notification send an AJAX request to clear the notification from the notification queue (JavaScript).

The notification queue should be saved in a database. Session or cookies aren't reliable for this.

However, this is just an assumption and the way *I* would implement a notification interface, but I guess the Facebook implementation is quite similar.

Comment: I use this approach. Database flag + jnotify = not elegant as facebook plus it does the trick with few lines of code.

Answer (score 4):

No *frelling* idea.

They probably save in a database whether or not you have checked the notification.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely not client side. Facebook likes to know as much about us as possible.

Comment: This should likely have been a comment...

Comment: @ircmaxell why is that? it answers the question `Cookies? Sessions? Databases? Javascript?`.

Comment: That's correct. Session objects are removed when the user logs off, javascript would be specific to each page, and cookies are unreliable as they can be removed or even disabled from the client browser. Storing the flag in the database would be the only reliable option.

Comment: I'm not saying it's not correct, I'm saying it should be a comment, since there's not much body here.  Take a peak at the comment on the question, it answers the OP better than this answer.  But that's just my opinion...

Answer (score 1):

### Client-side

You don't get to see inter-tab communication much, but it's awesome when used correctly, and provides some great advantages to your web application (such as saving on bandwidth).

I once had a great example, but I couldn't find it, so I'll show a quick prototype here.

I am assuming you have jQuery and jQuery Cookie plugin throughout the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var cookie = document.cookie;
    var timer = setTimeout(function(){
        if(document.cookie!=cookie){
            cookie = document.cookie;
            jQuery('#notes').text(jQuery.cookie('notes'));
        }
    }, 500);

    function send(msg){
        // update server
        /* you usually would do an ajax call here */
        // update client tabs
        jQuery.cookie('notes', msg);
    }
</script>

<div id="notes"></div>
<button onclick="send('Hi');" value="Hi"/>
<button onclick="send('Bye');" value="Bye"/>
```

### Server-side

On the server, they probably do not really need this notification data, so I would hazard a guess at a memory table (volatile storage) - it's fast and efficient. You can set PHP session to use these tables too if you want. Either case, there's nothing mysterious or out-of-this-world here, it's perfectly normal technology.